# Receive mails to main domain with another IP

Tags: email, email-server

Currently I have a domain with multiple public IPs, Example:

```
fakory.com -> 190.6.206.171 / Webserver PC1
fs3.fakory.com -> 190.6.206.173 / Mail Server PC2
```

I have tried to address `test@fs3.fakory.com` receive mails and working properly.

But when I try to receive emails from `test@fakory.com` failed to receive anything :( any Help??

Comment: I dont know if i will need to add another DNS Record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep -- you need to create an MX record in DNS for fakory.com to point to your mail server:

[wikipedia entry for MX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record)

How do to this will depend on what is serving your DNS, but it should be a very basic operation. It looks like you already have an MX record for fs3.fakory.com -- you want that same data in an MX record for fakory.com to get emails send to your domain to route properly.

Comment: could you be so kind friend to give me an example of that record that I have to add that it applies to my case? :)

Comment: Thank you very much Mate i setup the MX Record and now i can Receive Mails :D